# How to replace \n/g with <br /> in c#?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

In jQuery following code works

```
item[j].Comments.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")
```

Now I want to replace comment blank space with line break in Controller or View but not getting same result that jQuery shows.

Comment: Some more detail would be nice. Does that code compile (in C#)? What libraries/frameworks are you using? Do you have an existing controller and view?

Comment: If you have a string in C# and want to replace all the '\n's with '<br/>'s then you can use `myString = myString.replace("\n", "<br/>");`

Comment: yes code compiles In C#,i am using mvc5.yes I have controller and view.

Comment: fallaciousreasoning :i use ur code in view but its not working

Comment: You'll need to show a larger snippet of code in order for me to give you anything more useful.

Answer (score 0):

given :

```
string s = "Some text with newlines ....";
```

that would be :

```
s= s.Replace( Environment.NewLine, "<br/>" );
```

OR (not using environment)

```
s= s.Replace( "\r\n", "<br/>" ); //windows
s= s.Replace( "\r", "<br/>" ); //apple
s= s.Replace( "\n", "<br/>" ); //linux
```

So in your case :

```
item[j].Comments = item[j].Comments.Replace( Environment.NewLine, "<br/>" );
```